# How to style my view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have two taxanomy terms, A groups and B groups.

I have created a view of type node which displays the og groups of my site in grid style.
I have group the view with the taxanomy terms. Now my view looks like the following:

A groups
group1
group2
group3

B groups
group1
group2
group3

And I want it to display like the following:

A groups    B groups
group1       group1
group2       group2
group3       group3

What should I do for this type of styling.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need to make the grid display in multiple columns.  If your view settings, click the button to the right of `style: Grid` under "Basic Settings" then set the grid properties to something like:
[image: Grid Options]

Comment: But the A Groups and B groups are the categories of my groups. So I want to categorize my groups. So under the AGroups the groups in this category should display and under the BGroups the groups in this category should display. hope you will understand my problem.

Comment: @Ahmad Change the __Grouping field__ dropdown box to the taxonomy term then all the content with a taxonomy term "A" is under the A group and "B" is under the B group and play around with the __Number of columns__

Comment: Yes I have done this. But according to your method It displays just like in my question. The content with the taxonomy term A displays under the A group and "B" under the B group. And I want to display the taxonomy terms in one line. And the content of A should display under A and the content of B should display under B.

Comment: Please post a picture of your view settings or something, there is only so much that can be done without seeing what you have tried.